# Criar vários clientes de uma classe Clientes

Tags: python

Como eu poderia adicionar uma lista de clientes na classe Clientes?

```
class Clientes():
    def __init__(self, nome, cpf):
        self.nome = nome
        self.cpf = cpf


listaClientes = ['cliente1', 'cliente2', 'cliente3']
```

Se eu fizer um for, ele só vai gravar o último cliente por cima dos clientes anteriores.

```
for x in listaClientes:
    x = Clientes('nome','cpf')
```

Assim ele só registra o cliente 3 e perde os clientes 1 e 2.

Comment: qual vai ser a referencia dos objetos na memoria? x temporariamente vai ser o cliente 1, depois o cliente 2, e por ultimo o cliente 3, ficando este ultimo no x. os dois primeiros seram apagados

Comment: É exatamente esse o problema, não estou sabendo fazer essa referencia.

Comment: Pra que serve `listaClientes`, são os nomes dos clientes? E de onde virão os CPF's? E o que vc quer afinal, criar uma lista de `Clientes`? Aproveitando, o nome da classe não é bom, porque estando no plural dá a entender que ela representa vários clientes, quando na verdade ela representa apenas um...

Answer (score -1):

vc precisa de uma lista para isso

```
class Clientes():
        def __init__(self, nome, cpf):
            self.nome = nome
            self.cpf = cpf
    
    listaClientes = ['cliente1', 'cliente2', 'cliente3']
    
    cliente =[]
    for i in listaClientes:
        c = Clientes('nome','cpf')
        cliente.append(c)


for k in  cliente:
    print(k.nome,k.cpf)
```